# How to set default time and minute

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjq8U/1/) inside the view appointments tab,there is add timing button.When I click on the button then a new row gets added.Now when I click on  the calender icon then a pop comes up which shows the current hour and minutes.But I want it to show *00:00*. Can any body please tell me how to do?

I have tried to modify the *setDate* method inside the bootstrap date time picker  [source code](http://pastie.org/9188443)

```
setLocalDate: function (localDate) {
    if (!localDate) 
        this.setValue(null);
    else 
        this.setValue(Date.UTC(localDate.getFullYear(), localDate.getMonth(), localDate.getDate(), localDate.getHours(), localDate.getMinutes(), localDate.getSeconds(), localDate.getMilliseconds()))
},
```

to

```
setLocalDate: function (localDate) {
    if (!localDate) 
        this.setValue(null);
    else 
        this.setValue(00, 00, 00, 00,00, 00, 00))
},
```

but it did not work.Please anybody tell me what else do I have to change

Comment: @RobG thanks,I will try and let you know

Comment: @RobG I tried your way but it still shows the current time

Comment: I wouldn't go messing with the library anyway. According the to the (extremely minimal) [documentation](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/), you should be using `.datepicker('setValue', value)` where *value* can be "a string in the specified format or a Date object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RobG already said, you can simply set the value in the initialization routine

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker1 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(function () {
            $(element).parent().datetimepicker({
                pickDate: false,
                pickSeconds: false,
                minuteStep: 10
            });

            $(element).parent().datetimepicker('setValue', '00:00');
        });

// ...
```

See updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjq8U/11/)

*Update:*

If you want `00:00` as default value only, you must pick the value from the `valueAccessor` first and set `00:00`, if the value is undefined

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    $(function () {
        $(element).parent().datetimepicker({
            pickDate: false,
            pickSeconds: false,
            minuteStep: 10
        });

        var accessor = valueAccessor();
        var val = ko.unwrap(accessor) || '00:00';
        $(element).parent().datetimepicker('setValue', val);
    });

// ...
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjq8U/12/)

*Update:*

Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation about version 2.2.0.
Testing, if the accessor is a function, seems to work

```
var val = valueAccessor();
if (typeof(val) == 'function')
    val = val();

$(element).parent().datetimepicker('setValue', val || '00:00');
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjq8U/14/)

Comment: I want to show 00:00 only to dynamically created rows.For example when you click on the add timings button then a row gets added and to this date picker only I want to show 00:00.But I dont want to show older rows

Comment: its giving me error `uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`
at this line
`var val = ko.unwrap(accessor) || '00:00';`

Comment: May be there is version issue.The fiddle is using knockout 3 but in my project i am using knockout 2.2.0

Comment: I tried it with Knockout 2.2.0 and it complains about `ko.unwrap`. Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation about version 2.2.0.

Comment: I tried with ko.utils.unwrapObservable and it worked.replaced var val = ko.unwrap(accessor) || '00:00'; with var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(accessor) || '00:00';

Comment: Great, do you have a link to some documentation?

Comment: Can you come to stackoverflow chat?